# Passing type contructor as type parameter to macro

Tags: scala, scala-macros

i have the following macro which run smoothly when called with simple parameter T
( **Account**, **Article**, etc..) but  throws an error when called with a type constructor like **PurchaseOrder[LinePurchaseOrder]**

```
object MakeService {
def make[T]: DAO[T] = macro makeImpl[T]
def makeImpl[T: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context): c.Tree = {

import c.universe._
import com.xsoft.iws.shared.DAO
import com.xsoft.iws.shared.Model._
import com.xsoft.iws.dao.DAOObjects._
import com.xsoft.iws.services.Request._
val t = c.weakTypeOf[T].typeSymbol.name.toTypeName
val tc = c.weakTypeOf[T].typeConstructor

q"""
   implicit val api = new DAO[$t] {
      override def create():Int = {run.runG[Int](Create[$t])}
      override def all(): List[$t] = run.runG[List[$t]](new FindAll[$t])
      override def insert(model: List[$t]):Int = run.runG[Int](new Insert[$t](model))  
      override def findSome(id: String): List[$t] = run.runG[List[$t]](new FindSome[$t](id))
      override def findSome1(id: Long): List[$t] = run.runG[List[$t]](new FindSome1[$t](id))
      override def find(id: String): List[$t] = run.runG[List[$t]](new Find[$t](id)) 
      override def delete(id: String): Int = run.runG[Int](new Delete[$t](id))
      override def update(item: $t):Int = {
        val i = run.runG[List[$t]](new Find[$t](item.id))
        val k = if (i.size > 0) run.runG[Int](new Update[$t](item)) else run.runG[Int](new Insert[$t](List(item)))
        k
      }
   }
api
"""
}
```

when used like this:

```
 val  api  = MakeService.make[Vat]                              // ==> OK
 val  api  = MakeService.make[PurchaseOrder[LinePurchaseOrder]] // ==> NOT OK
```

Comment: From a cursory look, the problem seems to simply be that for some reason you're converting the full type (that is passed to you) into a TypeSymbol. `c.weakTypeOf[T]` is `typerOf[PurchaseOrder[LinePurchaseOrder]]`, but then you call `typeSymbol` on it, which gives the type symbol `PurchaseOrder` (the type parameter is lost) and finally you do `name.toTypeName` hence getting the type name `PurchaseOrder`. It seems to me that you just want to do `val t = c.weakTypeOf[T]` and that's it.

Comment: replacing the 
```val t = c.weakTypeOf[T].typeSymbol.name.toTypeName```
 with
```val t = c.weakTypeOf[T]```
did not solve the problem
it throws the following error

Comment: Which "following error"?

Comment: sorry. replacing the  

        ```val t = c.weakTypeOf[T].typeSymbol.name.toTypeName```
with 
        ```val t = c.weakTypeOf[T]``` 
solved the problem